# How can I allow users to tab to a locked control?

Tags: user-interface, vb6, properties

I've locked a control in VB6 but left it enabled so the contents can be copied. However doing so has removed the control from the tab order. Is there a way I can keep the locked control in the tab order so users can still jump to it without the mouse? The TabIndex property is still set to the desired value.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to reproduce.  I dropped three TextBoxes on a clean form and verified I could tab through all of them.  I set the Locked property of one of them to True and found I was still able to tab through all of them.

Is the TabStop property of the control you're having problems with set to True?

Comment: Hmmm. TabStop was true, but locking it set it to false. Resetting it after locking fixed the issue. Apparently this particular control overrides what Locked does.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting TabStop to True, make sure the TabIndex is set to a number that is exactly the order of how many tabs you want the user to hit before arriving at the text box.

A TextBox with a TabIndex of value 3 means that the user has to press the TAB key 3 times before activating the focus on the TextBox. In your case, the TabIndex might be 1000 or a negative value.